# jquery tag cloud error?

Tags: jquery, tags, tag-cloud

I've got a problem. I made a tag cloud thingy to my website, but it doesn't work :(

```
({
    tags: [{
        tag: 'asdasd',
        freq: '4'
    }]
}) {
    tag: 'asdasdsadasd',
    freq: '4'
}]
}) {
    tag: 'xcvxcvcx',
    freq: '2'
}]
}) {
    tag: 'cvbvcbcbvbcv',
    freq: '11'
}]
})
```

this is the response of the PHP file, and i'd like to get it with my html-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  //get tag feed
  $.getJSON("tagcloud.php?callback=?", function(data) {
    //create list for tag links
    $("<ul>").attr("id", "tagList").appendTo("#tagCloud");
    //create tags
    $.each(data.tags, function(i, val) {
      //create item
      var li = $("<li>");
      //create link
      $("<a>").text(val.tag).attr({title:"See all pages tagged with " + val.tag, href:"http://localhost/tags/" + val.tag + ".html"}).appendTo(li);
      //set tag size
      li.children().css("fontSize", (val.freq / 10 < 1) ? val.freq / 10 + 1 + "em": (val.freq / 10 > 2) ? "2em" : val.freq / 10 + "em");
      //add to list
      li.appendTo("#tagList");
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

I used this script from tuts.com to write it to screen. The PHP callback and return is

```
$response = $_GET["callback"] . $json;
echo $response;
mysql_close($server);
```

Please tell me why it is not work

---

Yes, i did what you suggested and its works fine.

But there are another problems. Now i can get the values. For example Gyökér.
My MySQL table is UTF8 general ci and my HTML is utf8 encoded also.

I'd like to make the PHP "echo $response" to be UTF8. Any suggestions? My script now looks like this

```
$response = $_GET["callback"] . $json; echo $response;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't understand this at all:

```
({ tags:[{tag:'asdasd',freq:'4'}]}){tag:'asdasdsadasd',freq:'4'}]}){tag:'xcvxcvcx',freq:'2'}]}){tag:'cvbvcbcbvbcv',freq:'11'}]})
```

Are you intending something more like this:

```
{ tags:[    {tag:'asdasd',freq:'4'},
            {tag:'asdasdsadasd',freq:'4'},
            {tag:'xcvxcvcx',freq:'2'},
            {tag:'cvbvcbcbvbcv',freq:'11'}
        ]
};
```